# VB.net newbie trying to convert some c# code

Tags: vb.net, anonymous-function, anonymous-methods, c#-to-vb.net

I've been having trouble converting the following fairly straight forward c# code into vb.net 4.0, which I understand has anonymous delegates.  I just havn't been able to figure it out yet.

```
_combo.DataBound += (sender, args) =>
                                    {
                                        var item = _combo.FindItemByValue(values[0].ToString());
                                        if (item != null)
                                            item.Selected = true;
                                    };
```

I have tried the following

```
_combo.DataBound += Function(sender, args)
                                        Dim item = _combo.FindItemByValue(values(0).ToString())
                                        If item IsNot Nothing Then
                                            item.Selected = True
                                        End If

                                    End Function
```

But the compiler complains that DataBound can not be called directly, but has to be called with RaiseEvents

Comment: I'm not a .net type, but I'm genuinely curious (in passing) as to why anyone would want to convert code from c# to vb.  I'm sure there's a good reason, but what is it?

Comment: This is pulled from a forum post for an issue I am working on at work.  The project is vb.net (not my forte.) and the discussion about the issue I am dealing with is all in c#.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Makes sense. My condolences.

Comment: Anonymous delegates in VB.NET have to be single line. To do the above in single line is a challenge, or you need to call an intermediate function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AddHandler _combo.DataBound, Function(sender, args)... End Function is I think proper syntax.

Comment: This is the proper way to do it inline with an anonymous delegate, thanks.  See my answer for a way to change it into a usual event and delegate.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it figured out.

declare an event

> Private Event OnCombo_DataBound(ByVal values
>   As ArrayList)

Use RaiseEvent to fire it

```
RaiseEvent OnCombo_DataBound(values)
```

Create a handler for the event

```
 Private Sub Combo_DataBound(ByVal values As System.Collections.ArrayList) Handles OnCombo_DataBound
                Dim item = _combo.FindItemByValue(values(0).ToString())
                If item IsNot Nothing Then
                    item.Selected = True
                End If
            End Sub
```